# Expand a Gantt chart automatically to textwidth of a page

Tags: pgfgantt

I want nearly every Gantt-Chart to fit **automatically** to the textwidth of a page. The big word in that question is **automatic**. And that is what it differs from other questions like that.

The *textwidth* and the *count of timeslots* in the chart are not specified. The solution should be flexible enough to take care of it.

Maybe there is a solution to *calculate* `x unit`? The MWE below has 122 timeslots. So I would set `x unit` to `\textwidth divided by 122`. Is there a way to do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % show page borders
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{ganttchart}
    [
        x unit=1.23mm,              % timeslot width
        time slot format=isodate    % Datumsformat
    ]
    {2017-04-01}{2017-07-31}        % from-to (122 days)

    \gantttitle{Gantt-Chart with 122 timeslots}{122}\\
    \ganttbar{Short}{2017-05-01}{2017-06-01}\\
    \ganttbar{Long Long}{2017-05-25}{2017-06-04}\\
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've updated the answer with a cleaner syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following discussion in chat, this is an adaption of Alan's answer which implements the syntax he was trying to realise.

```
% addaswyd o ateb Alan Munn: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364944/expand-a-gantt-chart-automatically-to-textwidth-of-a-page/364969#364969 a chwestiwn buhtz: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364944/expand-a-gantt-chart-automatically-to-textwidth-of-a-page
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % show page borders
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
  /pgfgantt/time slots/.code={%
    \tikzset{%
      /pgfgantt/time slots/.cd,
      #1,
      /pgfgantt/.cd,
    }%
  },
  /pgfgantt/time slots/.search also={/pgfgantt},
  /pgfgantt/time slots/.cd,
  width/.store in=\ts@width,
  width=\textwidth,
  slots/.store in=\totaltimeslots,
  slots=20,
  label width/.store in=\ts@labelwidth,
  label width=25mm,
  calc x unit/.code n args=3{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ts@xunit{(#1-#2-0.6667em-2*\pgflinewidth)/#3}%
    \tikzset{%
      /pgfgantt/x unit=\ts@xunit pt,
    }%
  },
  widest/.code={%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ts@wdlabel{width("#1")}%
    \tikzset{/pgfgantt/time slots/label width=\ts@wdlabel pt}%
  },
  calc x unit aux width/.style={/pgfgantt/time slots/calc x unit={#1}{\ts@labelwidth}{\totaltimeslots}},
  calc x unit aux label width/.style={/pgfgantt/time slots/calc x unit={\ts@width}{#1}{\totaltimeslots}},
  calc x unit aux slots/.style={/pgfgantt/time slots/calc x unit={\ts@width}{\ts@labelwidth}{#1}},
  width/.forward to=/pgfgantt/time slots/calc x unit aux width,
  slots/.forward to=/pgfgantt/time slots/calc x unit aux slots,
  label width/.forward to=/pgfgantt/time slots/calc x unit aux label width,
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}
    [
        time slots={slots=122, widest=Long Long},
        time slot format=isodate,
    ]
    {2017-04-01}{2017-07-31}        % from-to (122 days)

    \gantttitle{Gantt-Chart with 122 timeslots}{\totaltimeslots}\\
    \ganttbar{Short}{2017-05-01}{2017-06-01}\\
    \ganttbar{Long Long}{2017-05-25}{2017-06-04}\\
\end{ganttchart}

\begin{ganttchart}
    [
        time slots/slots=15,
        time slots/widest=Foo,
        time slots/width=.9\linewidth,
        time slot format=isodate,
    ]
    {2017-04-01}{2017-04-15}        % from-to (122 days)
    \gantttitle{Gantt-Chart with 15 timeslots}{15}\\
    \ganttbar{Foo}{2017-05-25}{2017-06-04}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. Impressiv! What does `time slots/width=.9\linewidth,` do?

Comment: @buhtz Alan thought I should post it after I answered his query in chat. `time slots/width=.9\linewidth` sets the total width (label on the left + chart on the right) to 90% of the current width of a line. (Here, that is `\textwidth`, but `\linewidth` does not always equal `\textwidth` e.g. in a 2-column document or a special environment.)

Comment: @buhtz Note that `time slots={width=<dim>}` is equivalent to `time slots/width=<dim>`. The use of `time slots/`means I'm not overwriting any use `pgfgantt` or Ti*k*Z makes of a key called `width`. (Otherwise, I'd need a different name for the key.)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `calc` package to set the length as you need. Since the number of timeslots needs to be set manually in the `\ganttitle` command, I've created a `ganttchart` style `timeslots` which takes as its arguments the number of slots for the chart, and the text of the longest `\gantttitle` label (comma separated) and then uses that to calculate the width. It also sets the value of a macro `\timeslots` which can then be used in the `\gantttitle` command.

I've added the code as a `ganttchart` style, so that it can be specified without its own macro as in the previous version (see edit history for details).  I've also added a length for the width that you want the autosizing to be relative to.  For your specific example, it's set to `\textwidth`, but this allows you to set it to any width you like.

Usage: `[ ..., timeslots={<number>,<text of longest label>}, ... ]`

```
\usepackage[]{geometry} % show page borders
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\myunitx}
\newlength{\autosizewidth}
\setlength{\autosizewidth}{\textwidth} % this allows you to change the value for autosizing
\newcommand*{\timeslots}{}
\ganttset{
timeslots/.code args={#1,#2}{\setlength{\myunitx}{(\autosizewidth-\widthof{#2}-1em)/#1}
                 \renewcommand{\timeslots}{#1}\pgfkeys{pgfgantt/x unit=\myunitx}}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}
    [
        timeslots={122,Long Long},  % timeslots
        time slot format=isodate    % Datumsformat
    ]
    {2017-04-01}{2017-07-31}        % from-to (122 days)

    \gantttitle{Gantt-Chart with 122 timeslots}{\timeslots}\\
    \ganttbar{Short}{2017-05-01}{2017-06-01}\\
    \ganttbar{Long Long}{2017-05-25}{2017-06-04}\\
    \end{ganttchart}

\begin{ganttchart}
    [
        timeslots={15,Foo},         % timeslots
        time slot format=isodate    % Datumsformat
    ]
    {2017-04-01}{2017-04-15}        % from-to (122 days)
    \gantttitle{Gantt-Chart with 15 timeslots}{15}\\
    \ganttbar{Foo}{2017-05-25}{2017-06-04}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: This is great. Thx. But while minimizing my example I forgot the width of the text when using `ganttbar{}`. Couldn't get `widthof{My Bar}` working here.

Comment: @buhtz Can you update your example and I'll try to fix.

Comment: @buhtz Ok, I see the problem.

Comment: @buhtz I've fixed the problem. I'm not totally happy with the syntax, but it works as you need.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works fine! You are right, the code is impressionistic. I contacted the pgfgantt maintainer and pointed him to your solution. Hope he will integrate it into his package or minimaly into its documentation.

Comment: I am sorry, but the maintainer is not active. And there is not ticket system for that package to keep track on it.